# iOS AutoLayout Problems - Subviews Misplaced Even Though No Constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, constraints

I have a project where some of my views use constraints and some of them don't really need to because they show up nicely on other device sizes as well. My problem is that when I deleted all my constraints in a view controller's subviews, The subviews get heavily misplaced even though I didn't get any warnings about missing constraints.

Also, when I try to "reset all my subviews to suggested constraints", this adds no constraints whatsoever, and I'm stuck with misplaced views.

What could be the cause of this? Constraints are very tricky to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because,`AutoLayout` in XCode is default enabled.
Even you do not create any your constraints, XCode will auto create some constraints at build time so that iOS will know how to render the views

If you want to disable autoLayout,just uncheck the `Use auto layout` as image shown below

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to tell Xcode to not set their own constraints for certain view controllers? I developed my first app with Auto Layout enabled without using any constraints whatsoever and it turned out perfectly fine.

Comment: @Rafi If you dont what constraint for only one particular view controller, it would not be possible via storyboard. But you can take a seprate .xib and disable auto layout for that xib

Comment: Although I'm disappointed with the bad news...I guess I have no choice to disable auto layout. I guess I'm going to have to ask another question on how to implement swipeable table cells without constraints. Thanks guys. :)

Comment: I'm still a little confused though. From this website: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1, I read: "The automatic constraints give your views a fixed size and position. In other words, the view always has the same coordinates as you see in the storyboard. This is very handy because it means you can largely ignore Auto Layout. You simply don’t add constraints if the default ones are sufficient and only create constraints for those views that need special rules." Apparently this isn't working for me :(

Comment: Nevermind, I found out what I was doing wrong, some of my image were set to aspect fill but I forgot to check "clip subviews" which ensures that the image is the same size. But you guys were right though. Thanks for all the help!